# Can I access a variable in my lua script from another imported lua script?

Tags: lua

I have two Lua script files. I want to import file B into file A and allow file A to access the functions/variables of file B. Is this possible?

I'm using Lua 5.4.

**A.lua**

```
-- File A - Returns Nil, even though File B declares ImportedVar
dofile("B.lua");
function main()
    print(ImportedVar);
end
main();
```

**B.lua**

```
-- File B
print("File Loaded"); -- This prints
local ImportedVar<const> = 5; -- This can not be accessed from A.lua for some reason... (it just says that it is nil)
```

Comment: Only global variables are visible across different script files.

Comment: Lua is not python; have a look at the Programming in Lua book for a good explanation of how scoping works in Lua.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit awkward, but you can put variables that you want to make public in a global table and return it at the end of your module:

```
MyLib.lua
```

```lua
print("Loaded MyLib")
local importantVariable = 42

local function importantFunction ()
  return importantVariable
end

return { importantVariable = importantVariable,
         importantFunction = importantFunction, }
```

Then, to import the module use `require`:

```
MyMain.lua
```

```lua
local MyLib = require "MyLib"

io.write(string.format("importantVariable is: %d\n",
                       MyLib.importantVariable))
io.write(string.format("importantFunction returns: %d\n",
                       MyLib.importantFunction()))
```

Running `myMain.lua`:

```
$ lua -i myMain.lua 
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
Loaded MyLib
importantVariable is: 42
importantFunction returns: 42
```

Comment: On version 5.4, calling "require" results in an error "attempt to call a nil value (global 'require')".

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've been waiting for a bugfix release of 5.4, so I haven't installed it yet, but [the Lua 5.4 manual still shows `require` just as it was before](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-require). You could use `local MyLib = dofile "MyLib.lua"`.

Comment: @Rick -- _"calling `require` results in an error..."_ -- I'm not sure what you were doing with this; the code I posted above still works in Lua 5.4.6.

Answer (score 1):

**A.lua**

```
local bLib = dofile ("B.lua")
print(bLib.someVar)
print(bLib.someFunction())
```

**B.lua**

```
print("B loaded")
local bLib={}
bLib.someVar = 7

function bLib.someFunction ()
  return "Hello"
end

return bLib
```

**Run A.lua**

```
$ lua -i A.lua
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
B loaded
7
Hello
```

Hope that this helps

Answer (score 0):

I like to combine both - require() and load()...

```
-- File: test.lua
-- Lets return all the stuff...
return {
cat=[[return function(cat)
for line in io.lines(cat) do
 io.write(string.format('%s\n',line))
end
end]],
free=[[return function()
local a=(collectgarbage('count')*1024)
print('Before:',a,'Byte')
collectgarbage()
print('After:',(collectgarbage('count')*1024),'Byte')
a=a-collectgarbage('count')*1024
print('Freed:',a,'Byte')
return a
end]],
shell=[[return function(shell)
if (type(shell)=='string') then
 os.execute(shell)
else
 os.execute('/bin/bash')
end
end]],
cmd=[[return function(cmd)
cmd=io.popen(cmd, 'r')
cmd=cmd:read('a+')
return cmd
end]],
printf=[[return function(prf,...)
io.write(prf:format(...))
end]]
}
```

Lets play with in console...

```
# lua -i
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> test=require('test')
> test
table: 0x5666d290
> test.cat
return function(cat)
for line in io.lines(cat) do
 io.write(string.format('%s\n',line))
end
end
> cat=load(test.cat,'My file viewer')()
> cat
function: 0x56686810
> cat('test.lua')
return {
cat=[[return function(cat)
for line in io.lines(cat) do
 io.write(string.format('%s\n',line))
end
end]],
free=[[return function()
local a=(collectgarbage('count')*1024)
print('Before:',a,'Byte')
collectgarbage()
print('After:',(collectgarbage('count')*1024),'Byte')
a=a-collectgarbage('count')*1024
print('Freed:',a,'Byte')
return a
end]],
shell=[[return function(shell)
if (type(shell)=='string') then
 os.execute(shell)
else
 os.execute('/bin/bash')
end
end]],
cmd=[[return function(cmd)
cmd=io.popen(cmd, 'r')
cmd=cmd:read('a+')
return cmd
end]],
printf=[[return function(prf,...)
io.write(prf:format(...))
end]]
}
```

So the first step with require loads the code in a table with strings.
The second step do a load() to transform string code to function.
A special require() let you grab only what you want...

```
cat=require('test').cat
-- Now cat holds the string with function defining
-- Lets make a function from it...
cat=load(cat,'This is showing up as source with debug.getinfo()')()
cat
function: 0x5666dca0
-- Now it is ready for use
```

> The strings in `[[]]` can also hold Lua bytecode that load() convert correctly to whatever it is. But it is not trivial to store the key/value pairs. So i dont give a example about that. But a dump function example for saving bytecode can be found on SO.

Comment: Also tested successfull with Lua 5.4.0 - But i miss the history ( formerly typed commands with cursor up ) so i like Lua 5.3.5 more